# C# - Reading specific elements of an XML file into a dataGridView and display rest in textbox

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, filter

Hi I'm faced with a problem that I'd like some help with. Firstly I have an XML file here

```
    <data>
<row>
  <id>1</id>
  <description>description 1</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-12T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>some notes1asdsadsadsad</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>2</id>
  <description>description 2</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-15T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes> </somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>3</id>
  <description>description 3</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-21T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>bobobobojkfjh</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>4</id>
  <description>description 4</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-17T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>adaad</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>5</id>
  <description>description 5</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-24T00:21:04.803</thedate>
  <somenotes>zcxzc</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>6</id>
  <description>description 6</description>
  <thedate>2012-12-01T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>ssss</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>7</id>
  <description>description 11</description>
  <thedate>2013-05-16T00:21:04.803</thedate>
  <somenotes> </somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>8</id>
  <description>description 21</description>
  <thedate>2013-05-07T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>notes 2</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>9</id>
  <description>description 31</description>
  <thedate>2013-01-17T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes> </somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>10</id>
  <description>description 41</description>
  <thedate>2013-01-11T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes> </somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>11</id>
  <description>description 51</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-03T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes> </somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>12</id>
  <description>description 61</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-01T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>some other notes</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>13</id>
  <description>desc 55</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-25T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>aSAdaD

D
Ad
aDa</somenotes>
</row>
<row>
  <id>14</id>
  <description>desc 99</description>
  <thedate>2013-06-24T00:00:00</thedate>
</row>
<row>
  <id>15</id>
  <description>desk 888</description>
  <thedate>2013-05-10T00:00:00</thedate>
</row>
<row>
  <id>16</id>
  <description>test again</description>
  <thedate>2013-05-02T00:00:00</thedate>
  <somenotes>\ad</somenotes>
</row>
</data>
```

I have created a simple windows form application with a dataGridView and testBox. Here is what I would like to do:

1. I want to only load the "id", "description" and "thedate" elements to the dataGridView as the columns and then have the "somenotes" appear in the testBox when the corresponding cell is clicked in the dataGridView
2. I would also like to be able to filter the dataGridView using the "thedate" element so that i can filter by today, this week, this month, this year using buttons on the form.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I'm quite inexperienced using XML files with c#. I want to do this in the simplest way possible so nothing has to be very sophisticated and again thanks.

Comment: Use linq to XML http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023090/linq-to-xml-and-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

1.Read xml to dataTable.

2.Binding datasource of dataGridView to dataTable.

3.Set display of coloumn in the dataGridView.